# node 0.12.x const in strict mode issue

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm running node v0.12.7, and installed protractor through npm.
Now I'm trying to run the conf.js using this [simple tutorial](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial), and I get the following error when executing the command `protractor conf.js`:

```
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
C:\Users\ramtin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:25
const builder = require('./builder');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ramtin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\protractor.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Can't update node due to dependency issues it will produce (I'm working on an already-built project which used node 0.12.17).

Using `--harmony` flag on protractor doesn't work. Do I need to install a specific version of protractor to be compatible with node 0.12.7? Or should I use `babeljs` to compile `ES6` to `ES5`?

If `babeljs` is the answer, how would I use it for protractor?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Do I need to install a specific version of protractor to be compatible with node 0.12.7

You need protractor version 2.

From https://github.com/angular/protractor#compatibility

[image]